# Change WooCommerce processing order email notification recipient to a custom address

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

When the order status in WooCommerce is set from **pending** to **processing** I can send an email to my customer. But I need to send an email only to a custom email adresse instead of the customer default address.

Is there a hook or filter for the `functions.php` file?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This custom function hooked in `woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order` filter hook, will do the job *(Set in it your replacement email)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order', 'processing_order_replacement_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function processing_order_replacement_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;

    // Set HERE your replacement recipient email(s)… (If multiple, separate them by a coma)
    $recipient = 'name@example.com';
    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works

---

> To add the custom recipient to the customer email, you should use this instead *(if needed)*:
>
> ```
> $recipient .= ',name@example.com';
> ```